# How to create a Custom Page Template with LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

In Lightning App builder, the template I want isn't there.
My goal is to create a Custom Page Template with a Header section, and 2 side-by-side column sections.

If I'm using aura, I'd simply follow this guide
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_template_component.htm

I cannot find the equivalent guide for LWC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If such a feature existed, it would be mentioned in the [XML Configuration File Elements](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags) documentation. As it does not (at the time of this answer), this is presumably not possible at the moment. I didn't immediately find any suggestion that this is coming out in the next release or later, so we don't know when, or if, this might be added to LWCs. For now, this is an area you'll still need to use Aura for.

Comment: Is it possible that this because of lwc can be embedded in aura but not the other way around? That some standard lightning components are written in aura and therefore could not been used in lwc defined template?

Comment: @Damecek That's actually a good point. Maybe they will pull that trigger some day to "force" us to go to LWCs (I'm already LWC exclusive unless absolutely required), but there's no way we can predict that at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer but rather an observation: If we examine html code  for pages built on standard and custom template we'll see for the standard template:

`<flexipage-lwc-app-home-template-header-two-columns-left-sidebar class="forcegenerated-flexipage-template" flexipage-lwcapphometemplateheadertwocolumnsleftsidebar_lwcapphometemplateheadertwocolumnsleftsidebar-host="">`

for the custom template:

`<flexipage-aura-template-wrapper class="forcegenerated-flexipage-template">`

Which may suggest standard template is LWC when custom is AURA

My problem is: List View displays differently in these two situations- on standard template it displays a a table, when on custom template it displays as a set of cards